# Cannot upgrade pandas on Pycharm

Tags: python, pip

When I enter the command `pip install pandas==1.3.0` on a virtual environment from PyCharm, I get the following error.

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> pandas==1.3.0 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2,
> 0.4.3, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0 .14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.22.0, 0.23.0, 0.23.1, 0.23.2, 0.23.3, 0.23.4, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.24.2, 0.25.0, 0.25.1, 0.25.2, 0 .25.3, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2,
> 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5) ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas==1.3.0

Comment: Pandas 1.3.0 is suported from Python 3.7.1 and upwards, which version of Python are you using? I'm guessing 3.6.1, since the latest supported release from the error is 1.1.5, which is the last Pandas version to support that version of Python.

Comment: Yea looks like I am using the older version (3.6) of Python. Is there a way to upgrade to a newer version on pycharm?

Comment: It's not PyCharm that requires an update, but you need to install a newer version of Python. The way you would go about that is completely OS dependent, and I would suggest looking up the appropriate version for your system.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas 1.3.0 requires "Python >= 3.7.1". See on [Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/1.3.0/):

[image: Metadata of pandas package on pypi]

Since you are using Python 3.6, if you wish to use this version of pandas, you need to use a different Python version (">= 3.7.1").